# Twilio Notifications for Business Side

Tags: twilio

How can my company (3-4 people) be notified that we have a new text within Twilio via our phones when we are out of the office?

Comment: Is there an application that you’ve connected Twilio to that you use during business hours? You might also check out this support article: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134287-Forwarding-SMS-messages-to-another-phone-number

Comment: ArborGold is connected to it during business hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Twilio Programmable SMS product to notify one or more phones.

https://www.twilio.com/sms

You can either use a Webhook pointing to your own backend setup or use their Functions console.

Comment: Okay, I have wrote the Webhook. Now where do I place it?